# grails call taglib from quartz job

Tags: grails, quartz-scheduler

I have a quartz job that calls the joda taglib (but could be any other).

I do it like this:

```
def joda = grailsApplication.mainContext.getBean('grails.plugin.jodatime.taglib.FormattingTagLib')

def formatDate = joda.format(value:event.startDate, style:"SS", locale:user.locale, zone:user.timeZone)
```

But I am gettng:

```
org.quartz.JobExecutionException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request. [See nested exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No thread-bound request found: Are you referring to request attributes outside of an actual web request, or processing a request outside of the originally receiving thread? If you are actually operating within a web request and still receive this message, your code is probably running outside of DispatcherServlet/DispatcherPortlet: In this case, use RequestContextListener or RequestContextFilter to expose the current request.]
```

Which absolutely makes sense because a quartz job is not request bound as it is triggered by time and not by request.

I searched around but could not find a propper sollution. Can somebdy give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is `joda.format()` attempts to get the current request, which as you noted, is not possible.

But more fundamentally, taglibs are for GSPs. Calling them outside of GSPs is not a good practice because it is outside the use case of taglibs. Fortunately, the solution is simple: use the joda time formatter directly:

```
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat

def formatter = DateTimeFormat.forStyle('SS').withLocale(user.locale).withZone(user.timeZone)
def formatDate = formatter.print(event.startDate)
```

https://github.com/gpc/joda-time/blob/grails2/grails-app/taglib/grails/plugin/jodatime/taglib/FormattingTagLib.groovy

The answer to how to call taglib from quartz job is not to do it at all.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I also came up with the sollution by using the DateTimeFormatter. But I can't accept your answer because you gave (a good) sollution to my problem but the question was how I can call a TagLib inside a quartz job

Comment: Also it is not the joda TagLib that is attempting to get the current request (because I am passing the locale attribute and therefore the request is never used). Its a general issue to all TagLibs. They are just not entering the code block. Event if I do a log.debug at the very beginning of the TagLib method

Comment: And my answer to that was that you simply don't. I'm sure it's possible, but it'd be like pulling teeth because you'd have to inject a request so that the taglib thinks it's running under normal circumstances. The better solution, at least for custom taglibs, is to put the common code elsewhere, such as a service, and call it from the job and taglib. For third-party taglibs, unfortunately you'd have some code duplication. Once again, the answer to *how to call taglib from quartz job* is not to do it at all.

Comment: Ok. You are right. Calling a TagLib from any other then a gsp is just wrong by architecture. Please put the last sentence in your answer to answer the question. I'll mark it as accepted